# Smooth transition between divs with disabled scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm currently making a one-page site. I wanted it to have disabled scrolling and transitions similar to these in here: http://www.fk-agency.com/ (as in, user can only move to certain part of the website after clicking a link). I was convinced it should be rather simple, so I started with the obvious:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg1">ASDFG
    <a href="#bg2">kfhakfj</a></div>
<div id="bg2">QWERT</div>
<div id="bg3">ZXCVB</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bg1{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

#bg2{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:bisque;
}

#bg3{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:menu;
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    scale();
    $(window).resize(scale);    


    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var target=this.hash,
            $target=$(target);

        $('html,body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':$target.offset().top
                                      },900,'swing',function(){
                                          window.location.hash=target;
                                      })
    })

});

$(window).on("mousewheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

E: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yhpqn/4/

But then, surprise - it doesn't really work. I was trying to fault the bit that disables the scrolling, but even when I delete it, the transition still won't be smooth.

Will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Can you expand on `it doesn't really work`, looks fine to me in chrome

Comment: Check out webkit css transform transitions to make really smooth animations

Comment: Sure thing. When you click the link, it takes you to another part with a 'jump'. And I want it to smoothly scroll to this part. 
@Jervelund I tried to actually put some transitions on it, but seems to me I'm a moron, cause even when I do that, another section simply jumps in instead of sliding with ease.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in the jsfiddle... (You can choose a library on the left top)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yup, thank you for noticing :) Edited already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I re-wrote the code just a bit. Also I'm not sure if you were calling `scale()` from somewhere else but that was not defined in your fiddle and was breaking your script

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var target= $(this).attr("href");
       $target=$(target);

       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$target.offset().top},900,'swing');
    });

 });

 $(window).on("mousewheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhpqn/5/)